# Convert 32 bits .def file to 64 bits

Tags: c++, visual-c++, function, name-decoration

In my company we use `.def` files to specify the symbols that need to be exported. (I wish I could use a more modern and automated technique, unfortunately, the guys who decide live back in the eighties).

Writing a `.def` file by hand, using manual copy-paste is boring and error-prone but so far I can live with it.

However, I need to write a similar `.def` file for the 64 bits version of the DLL. The name decoration of several function changed and I wonder if there is a way to generate a `.def` file for the 64 bits version from the 32 bits version.

Are you aware of any tool that might help me ? Is this even realistic ? I really don't feel like I want to do it by hand one more time. Any solution, even one that involves coding my own tool, is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I was alive back in the 80's too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably __declspec(dllexport) the symbols I wanted, compile, and then run dumpbin /exports on the resulting DLL to get the mangled names, and then you can remove the __declspec and make a .def file.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the idea. Sounds effective. However I'd like to reduce modifications to the source code to a minimum. I guess using a macro to conditionally put/remove the `__declspec` statement without modifying the source code should work ?

Comment: Adding a macro or adding __declspec is going to change the code the same amount.  I don't see any risk there.

But if you really don't want to change code I guess you could compile it as debug, load an EXE that does loadlibrary on the DLL into windbg and do "x Mymodule!*" which will list all the symbols and then you can pick the ones you want out of there.

Answer (score 1):

Tell your boss to go back to the 80's. Seriously, this is not a portable way to export symbol names. What if the C++ compiler changes the name mangling scheme? Then you'd have to do this (what jcopenha said) all over again. What if you don't work there when it happens? Is another poor soul going to have to spend valuable time to find out what and how to do it? I would try to convince the boss to use `__declspec(dllexport)`. It'll save time now, and possibly time in the future.

I am assuming you are exporting classes and overloaded functions. If you are not, then I'd export the functions with C names instead. Those names are not mangled, and will not change.

Comment: I am indeed exporting classes. They want to use `.def` file to "hide" the function name and use ordinal numbers instead (to prevent user from guessing what functions are exported...) I believe this is an awful reason and that it won't stop any gifted "hacker" to find the functions signatures.

Comment: Ouch. Well, I would try to automate it in the build process. Create a separate build solution that uses __declspec() (hidden in a macro that expands to nothing in regular builds). Run dumpbin on the output, and create a .def file based on the dumpbin results, and merge it into the project. That way it's fairly automated, and will not blow up if you ever switch to a different compiler. You just have to remeber to use the macro.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning behind the comment about name mangling scheme changes introducing problems for DEF files. I thought DEF files would be a way to *avoid* name mangling change problems because when you use dllexport, you get mangled names, but when you use a DEF file, you specify the names, and they go into the exports un-mangled in my experience.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN he's exporting C++ names (mangled such). Well, you could "rename" them in the export, but you'd still have to point to the mangled C++ names. It's just not worth it. (I don't think anybody at Microsoft ever envisioned to use .def files like this)

Comment: In my def file, at least when dealing with a flat dll exporting simple global functions, I just list each global function name, and that's the name that gets exported. Maybe this is essentially C exporting and not C++?

Comment: Yes.  If you download dependency walker (http://dependencywalker.com/) and look at a DLL that exposes a C++ class (for instance) with __declspec(dllexport), you will see the mangled C++ names. The name mangling scheme is a compiler implementation detail, so whenever Microsoft feels like changing the mangling scheme, you'd have to quite possibly rewrite the entire .def file again. C functions are "simple names", and are standardised if I'm not mistaken.